Configuring Istio for HTTPS WebSocket Connection
I'm trying to configure Istio to enable HTTPS over a WebSocket connection. I'm using the default Istio sample as a starting point. Below is my current configuration:
Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tornado
  namespace: bookinfo
  labels:
    app: tornado
    service: tornado
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    name: http
  selector:
    app: tornado
 
Deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tornado
  namespace: bookinfo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tornado
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tornado
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tornado
        image: hiroakis/tornado-websocket-example
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888

Gateway:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: tornado-gateway
  namespace: bookinfo
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
 
VirtualService:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tornado
  namespace: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - tornado-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: tornado
      weight: 100

The current configuration works over HTTP, but I need to convert it to HTTPS. I'm looking for the proper changes to:
Use HTTPS on the tornado-gateway.
Ensure WebSocket traffic is still supported when switching to HTTPS.
I tried configuring Istio for HTTPS over WebSocket, expecting secure connections with WebSocket support, but it didn't work as expected
